# How to change Javascript based css properties in a component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component

I use [vue-form-wizard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-form-wizard) component which its initial design looks like this

[image]

and I managed to change the styles to match my needs but with 2 problems.

**First**: wizard is meant to start before bullets and the progress width is calculated using JavaScript in internal files located in node modules.

I need to change the width based on the new styles I made because the pre-calculated one doesn't cover 100% of the progress at the end.
The problem is shown here

[image]

in order to prevent changing anything internally 
, **Is there a way to solve this with any method?**

How to target something written inside JS files and modify it?

**Second** the previous bullet return to its inactive state when the next one is active.

This is happening using a class being used and unused using JavaScript which remove and append an active state of the element.

> *I browsed the component GitHub issues and I couldn't found anything
>   useful there.*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but maybe you can use https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html - mixins for it. Please, let me know if it helps.